# Iterate through JSON without keys in Python

Tags: python, json

First of all: I really can't find any thread with the same problem, so I decided to open a new one.

I don't know, how you can iterate through a JSON document, that has no keys.

I have a document in this format:

```js
{'name': 'Bryan', 'age': 34, 'male': True, 'hometown': 'Boston'}
{'name': 'Anna', 'age': 25, 'male': False, 'hometown': 'Chicago'}
{'name': 'Jeff', 'age': 47, 'male': True, 'hometown': 'Vancouver'}
{'name': 'Maria', 'age': 58, 'male': False, 'hometown': 'Madrid'}
......
......
```

The problem is, that normally JSON documents have 'keys' in front of the braces like this e.g.:

```js
{ 
"student1:" {'name': 'Bryan', 'age': 34, 'male': True, 'hometown': 'Boston'}
"student2:" {'name': 'Anna', 'age': 25, 'male': False, 'hometown': 'Chicago'}
"student3:" {'name': 'Jeff', 'age': 47, 'male': True, 'hometown': 'Vancouver'}
"student4:" {'name': 'Maria', 'age': 58, 'male': False, 'hometown': 'Madrid'}
}
```

I don't know, how I can access on single names or ages without keys like "student1". I want to make a list, with just the names and a separate list with the ages.

I watched some videos on Youtube and reading many threads today, but I can't find a solution. 
Hope somebody can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a json document, but a jsonl document (json-lines), where each line is a json entry

Comment: @C.Nivs Each line is *not* a valid JSON value since JSON uses double-quotes for string literals.

Comment: _I don't know, how you can iterate through a JSON document, that has no keys._ Isn't each "dictionary" on its own line?

Comment: The answer that you accepted as the "best" answer does not work on the input file unless it is first modified because the input file does not, as I have mentioned at least now three times, JSON input. If you run against an unmodified input file, the *accepted* code will throw an exception.`json-lines` is the wrong tools for this problem. Did you even try my answer, which does not require modifying the input file?

Comment: @Booboo I tried to delete my answer, but I couldn't as it has been marked as accepted. I agree that your answer is better as it does not require any modification of the input to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As C.Nivs says in a comment, your document is `.jsonl`, where each line is a separate JSON object. You can use the [`json-lines`](https://pypi.org/project/json-lines/) package for handling your file (I had to wrap everything in double quotes for your example to work):

```py
import json_lines

with open('test.jsonl') as f:
    for item in json_lines.reader(f):
        print(item['name'])
```

Output:

```
Bryan
Anna
Jeff
Maria
```

Comment: Great! If you feel the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the little checkmark) so other users can know the question has recieved an answer.

Comment: _As C.Nivs says in a comment, your document is .jsonl, where each line is a separate JSON object._ It appears that may not be the case, per a [later comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216594/iterate-through-json-without-keys-in-python#comment108298193_61216594).

Comment: @AMC I agree. In this case, [Booboo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61217363/5637137) is probably the better one.

Answer (score 1):

Each line of the file is *not* a valid `JSON` string since `JSON` uses double-quotes for string literals. This solution does *not* use `JSON`.

You can use `literal_eval` from package `ast`, which safely evaluates a string that consists of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('test.json1') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = literal_eval(line)
        print(d['name'])
```

Prints:

```
Bryan
Anna
Jeff
Maria
etc.
```

[See documentation for ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval)